# Rails query condition or relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

It's my DB scheme:

```
branches
-----------------------------------
id
name:string
active:boolean
..

course_contents
-----------------------------------
id
title:string
show_all_branches:boolean
active:boolean
..

branches_course_contents
-----------------------------
branch_id
course_content_id
```

And my model files:

```
class Branch < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :course_contents
  scope :active, -> { where(active: true) }
end

class CourseContent < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :branches
  scope :active, -> { where(active: true) }
  scope :show_all_branches, -> { where(show_all_branches: true) }
end
```

I'm trying to `CourseContent.show_all_branches.merge(-> { joins(:branches) })` this command. It returns show_all_branches selected and has relations with branches table. But i need show_all_branches selected or has relations with branches table.

Comment: Assuming you want `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`, Try `CourseContent.show_all_branches.merge(-> { includes(:branches) })`

Comment: Thanks! But not working true way for me. It returns only show_all_branches selected in course_contents table. I need @branch.course_contents with show_all_branches selected rows together.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helps. I solved this problem and I writing my solution for other peoples. I said actually need to branch's course_contents with show_all_branches selected in the course_contents table. I tried merge method with this `CourseContent.show_all_branches.merge(-> { joins(:branches) })` or other many methods with other conditions. Cuz I used to joins/includes method all of my conditions. It's never returns true result for me. And I finally tried left_joins method and that solved my problem here.

My commands here:

```
@course.course_contents.active.left_joins(:branches).where("course_contents.show_all_branches = ? OR branches_course_contents.branch_id = ?", true, @branch.id)
```

Its sql result

```
SELECT "course_contents".* FROM "course_contents" LEFT OUTER JOIN "branches_course_contents" ON "branches_course_contents"."course_content_id" = "course_contents"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "branches" ON "branches"."id" = "branches_course_contents"."branch_id" WHERE "course_contents"."course_id" = 3 AND "course_contents"."active" = 't' AND (course_contents.show_all_branches = 't' OR branches_course_contents.branch_id = 1)
```

and its explain:

```
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "course_contents".* FROM "course_contents" LEFT OUTER JOIN "branches_course_contents" ON "branches_course_contents"."course_content_id" = "course_contents"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "branches" ON "branches"."id" = "branches_course_contents"."branch_id" WHERE "course_contents"."course_id" = $1 AND "course_contents"."active" = $2 AND (course_contents.show_all_branches = 't' OR branches_course_contents.branch_id = 1)  [["course_id", 3], ["active", true]]
  Branch Load (1424.1ms)  SELECT  "branches".* FROM "branches" WHERE "branches"."active" = $1 AND "branches"."slug" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["active", true], ["slug", "izmir"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```